# GDB - What thread am I on?

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, gdb

When I hit a breakpoint in GDB, and I need to find out what thread this is on, I do `info thr`. This prints out the list of all the threads in my program, and the current thread is marked with a `*`

Instead of having GDB dump the entire list of threads, and then manually reading what thread has the `*`, is there a command in gdb which simply prints out the current thread?

I need this because I am logging some behavior in my program. In other words, I have something like this -

```
(gdb) command 12
    >> p " xyz just happpened"
    >> whatThreadIsThis // I would like this
    >> c
    >> end
```

If GDB implemented something like the `whatThreadIsThis` command, then I could use GDB to log all occurrences of xyz with the threads they happened on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the "thread thread-id" command to switch to another thread as the docs mentions. What the docs doesn't seem to mention is that  without any argument, it just prints the current thread:

```
 (gdb) thread
 [Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7ffff7fc2700 (LWP 4641))]
```

Answer (score 6):

gdb also has [Convenience Variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html).
One of the them is:

```
$_thread

    The thread number of the current thread.
```

You can print it with:

```
(gdb) p $_thread
$2 = 2
```

Also it can be used in conditions:

```
condition 1 $_thread != 1
```